# mod_rewrite to keep subdomain in URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have this application that I want to support multi languages.
I thought the easiest way would be to use sub domains aka

```
http://fr.domain.com/content
```

Now I created the sub domain on my server, pointing to the main root and indeed, the above URL is accessible.
The problem now are all my links, which are absolute.
Is there a way with mod_rewrite to catch the language from the URL and than rewrite the links to the same sub domain URL?

So if we are on `http://fr.domain.com/content` and click the link `http://domain.com/link` I want the page to load as `http://fr.domain.com/link`

Is that possible?
Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would probably have to check HTTP_REFERER if you want to do this through apache. It might be good to start updating the site so that the links are dynamic in the future...

Something like (I can't really test this currently):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[a-z]{2}\.host\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://([a-z]{2})\.host.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1.host.com/$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

EDIT: removed a NOT in the 3rd condition

You might have to check some other conditions, but test things out to figure out what works. Plus, if you do other redirects you need a way to maintain the original referrer. In some ways even with the links the way they are, it may be easier to do this through a more dynamic means with php (through session) or something.

I was using these:

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html#HTTP_REFERER

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html

Comment: I agree that you probably want to update the site to alter the links before they are sent to the browser.  The solution above will work if you're only dealing with GETs, but if you have absolute links for POST requests, mod_rewrite is not the appropriate tool to tackle this problem.

Comment: True. Maybe it should be the "P" flag instead of the "L" flag to preserve the post data. (assuming proxy module is enabled)

Comment: Oh, my.. I completely forgot about my question. Sorry about that craniumonempty. I see that you only got half of the bounty.. I apologize. Your solution works great. Only catch is I would like to have English as the default language. I have a language switch with links like `href="it.domain.com"` etc. The English switch has a normal `href="domain.com"` and of course when we are for example on the French page `fr.domain.com` the referer still keeps the French sub. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: If the page is reached with no language or way to tell what language the user prefers, choose the default language. I'm unsure what your backend looks like.. if you don't have a dynamic language, point both en subdomain and no subdomain to English, if that is going to mess with your javascript, forward no domain to English (like a 301). If you have a dynamic language, then choose which language is given and default on English if you can't tell.

Also, I agree with simiko. There has to be a way to do rewrites and make them work with the CMS you are using. Try it and ask as another question.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need some kind of on-the-fly HTML rewriting tool like [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/). This tool was specically designed for rewriting the links in pages on the other side of a reverse proxy but it should be possible to use it for generic link rewriting. Specifically the docs say:

> Normally, mod_proxy_html will refuse to run when not in a proxy or when the contents are not HTML. This can be overridden (at your own risk) by setting the environment variable PROXY_HTML_FORCE (e.g. with the SetEnv directive).

The module is quite configurable and supports conditional rewriting and regexes so with some tweaking it should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

So you're saying your website has links like `<a href="http://domain.com/link">` instead of just `<a href="/link">`??? Is there some reason your links are coded like that?

Would you be happy with whipping out a text editor and search/replace'ing those hrefs instead of doing something a-typical or excessively complex with URL rewriting?

Comment: What CMS are you using? If it's something open source it'd be way easier to mod/fix the CMS software to write proper URLs.